# Android use JSoup parse HTML convert to String

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, android-parser

I am trying to use richtext to display html content so i was parse the url try to get all content inside `<div class="margin-box"></div>` to String value.
But i can not parse the url.
Code like below:

**User Soup parse the url**

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(news_url);
String news_content = CommonUtil.newsContent(document);
```

**Data Capture**

```js
    public static String newsContent(Document document){
        Elements elements = document.select("div.margin-box");
        String newsContent = elements.toString();
        return newsContent;
    }
```

**Then i get debug result:**
[image]

Show URL parse unsuccessful.
Actually i want to get value like below:

```html
<div>
<p>
<imgsrc="http://p1.pstatp.com/large/1c67000332373537f0ff" img_width="640" img_height="360" inline="0" alt=“************” onerror="javascript:errorimg.call(this);">
</p>
<p class="pgc-img-caption”>***********</p><p>*************************************</p>
<p><imgsrc="http://p3.pstatp.com/large/1c6e0000841ab42ca326" img_width="640" img_height="425" inline="0" alt=“**********”onerror="javascript:errorimg.call(this);"></p>
<p class="pgc-img-caption”>********************************</p>
<p><img src="http://p1.pstatp.com/large/1c6d00008eebccce3e2f" img_width="550" img_height="375" inline="0" alt=“************” onerror="javascript:errorimg.call(this);"></p>
<p class="pgc-img-caption”>*********</p><p>**************************</p><p>*********************</p><p>*****************</p></div>
```

**What did i do wrong?**

**Full HTML BLOCK**
[image]

There are no element inside div class
[image]

Comment: Can you post the web URL or complete html block?

Comment: OK i will edit and add full html block

Comment: @ProkashSarkari have add full html block

Comment: Your debug point is set to "document" which has the full html block instead of a div class. You already have the data just put a logcat and print the value of "newsContent"

Comment: @ProkashSarkar But there are no elements inside div class look at my new edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to first check, if JSoup can parse the content: http://try.jsoup.org/~8W0oCmiiYnFL01nUM6HDbQ9wwTA

You are using `Jsoup.parse` which [expects html stored in a string](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-). If you want to use parse to retrieve the html source you have to [pass a URL and a timeout](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.net.URL-int-):

```
String url = "http://servertrj.com/news/index/208";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
```

Most of the time you find the `get()` syntax to pull html source, compare your syntax to this simple example:

```
String url = "http://servertrj.com/news/index/208";
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).get();
Elements elements = doc.select(".margin-box");
System.out.println(elements.size() + "\n" + elements.toString());
```

Output:

```
1
<div class="margin-box"> 
<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; line-height: 30px; font-family: &quot;Microsoft YaHei;, SimSun, Verdana, Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 15px;">[... truncated because of spam detection, but same as try.jsoup]</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for comment you delay. your suggest is what i want It is work thank you very much!!